# PlayerPref is not getting stored properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im new to programming. I was able to store the Highscore.
Now i have the problem that its not working with the Money.
I am trying to store the Money so even if the game gets closed it will still be saved.
I watched alot of Videos about it but i am having kinda problems with understanding since its something new for me.

```
{
    public GameObject playButton;

    public GameObject Gameover;

    public GameObject ShopMenu;

    public Player player;
    public TMP_Text scoreText;

    public TMP_Text MoneyText;
    public int score;
    public int money;
    public TMP_Text highScore;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = 60;

        Pause();
    }

    public void play()
    {
        score = 0;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();

        playButton.SetActive(false);
        Gameover.SetActive(false);
        ShopMenu.SetActive(false);

        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        player.enabled = true;

        pipes[] pipes = FindObjectsOfType<pipes>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pipes.Length; i++)
        {
            Destroy(pipes[i].gameObject);
        }

        highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();

        if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
            highScore.text = score.ToString();
        }

        MoneyText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money").ToString();

        if (money != PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
            MoneyText.text = money.ToString();
        }
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;

        player.enabled = false;
    }

    public void GameOver()
    {
        Gameover.SetActive(true);
        playButton.SetActive(true);
        ShopMenu.SetActive(true);

        highScore.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0).ToString();

        if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", score);
            highScore.text = score.ToString();
        }

        MoneyText.text = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money").ToString();

        if (money != PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("money", money);
            MoneyText.text = money.ToString();
        }

        Pause();
    }

    public void IncreaseScore()
    {
        score++;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        money++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your error? By this code `money` is not assigned. maybe in your `play` assign `money  = 0` ? so `MoneyText.text = money.ToString();` i think will fail as calling tostring on a null.. Is weird.

Comment: `money` is int, so it cannot be null, but yes, this value is never assigned according to this piece of code

Comment: Its late on Saturday, of course it cant be null ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your `money` value is always `0` as you do not initialize it. The same is about the `score` value. Try to add

```
money = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("money", 0);
score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
```

to your `Awake()` method

Comment: I'm not familiar with unity, but seems worth moving the `score` too.

Comment: good point. corrected the answer